# Implementing the warp/liquify tool in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Im looking for a way to warp an image similar to how the liquify/IWarp tool works in Photoshop/Gimp.

I would like to use it to move a few points on an image to make it look wider than it was originally.

Anyone have any ideas on libraries that could be used to do this? I'm currently using OpenCV in the same project so if theres a way using that it would be easiest but I'm open to anything really

Thanks.

EDIT: Heres an example of what im looking to do https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJdWF.png
All I've done there is pulled a few points out sideways and thats what im looking to do from inside my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this search 'image warp operator source c++' i get:

..... Added function 'CImg ::[get_]warp()' that can warp an image using a deformation .... Added function 'CImg ::save_cpp()' allowing to save an image directly as a C/C++ source code. ...

then [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) could do well for you.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV's `remap` can accomplish this. You only have to provide x and y displacement maps. I would suggest you can create the displacement map directly if you are clever, and this would be good for brush-stroke manipulation similar to Photoshop's liquify. The mesh warp and sparse point map approach is another option, but essentially computes the displacement map based on interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at http://code.google.com/p/imgwarp-opencv/. This library seems to be exactly what you need: image warping based on a sparse grid.

Another option is, of course, generate displacements yourself and use cv::Remap() function of OpenCV.